# Output Bash pipes to Python-compatible format

Tags: python, bash, nlp, pipe, udpipe

I'm working on text tokenization and lemmatization using UDPipe models. I can complete the task itself by using `!echo` commands or printing into a file, but I would like to generate a Python data structure to further process the output.

## What works

Here is my working command:

```
!echo 'the text I'm processing' | ./udpipe --tokenize --tag './path/to/my/model'
```

Out:

```
Loading UDPipe model: done.
newdoc
newpar
sent_id = 1
text = прывітанне, сусвет
1   прывітанне  прывітанне  NOUN    NN  Animacy=Inan|Case=Nom|Gender=Neut|Number=Sing   _   _   _   SpaceAfter=No
2   ,   ,   PUNCT   PUNCT   _   _   _   _   _
3   сусвет  сусвет  NOUN    NN  Animacy=Inan|Case=Nom|Gender=Masc|Number=Sing   _   _   _   SpacesAfter=\n
```

This works for printing the output into a file:

```
!echo 'the text I'm processing' | ./udpipe --tokenize --tag './path/to/my/model' >> filename.txt
```

`./udpipe` is the cloned repository of the package

## What I tried (without success)

`os.system()`

```
import os
text = 'the text I'm processing'
cmd = "echo '{}' | ./udpipe --tokenize --tag './path/to/my/model'".format(text)
os.system(cmd)

Out: 0
```

`subprocess.getoutput()`

```
import subprocess
cmd = "'the text I'm processing' | ./udpipe --tokenize --tag './path/to/my/model'"
output = subprocess.getoutput(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
print(output)

TypeError: getoutput() got an unexpected keyword argument 'stdout'
```

Comment: `output = subprocess.check_output(["./udpipe", "--tokenize", "--tag", "./path/to/my/model"], input=text, text=True)`

Comment: Thank you very much! Not only it worked, but also it improved my understanding of Bash. Maybe you want to post this as an answer so that I accept it?

Comment: Be careful with quoted text.  `text = 'the text I'm processing'` is not valid syntax.  It should be `text = 'the text I\'m processing'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've done some research and found `subprocess` module, which is the most common way to call processes from Python. If you want to use functionality of shell *(such as pipe)* you need to pass argument `shell=True` to any function which actually call process, e.g. [`subprocess.Popen()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen), the basic one.

```py
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

text = "the text I'm processing"
cmd = "echo", text, "|", "./udpipe", "--tokenize", "--tag", "./path/to/my/model"
proc = Popen(cmd, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, text=True, shell=True)
output, _ = proc.communicate()
print(output)
```

In your example you've also used `>>` to append output to file, so no output will be produced and you can just wait for process end:

```py
from subprocess import Popen

text = "the text I'm processing"
cmd = "echo", text, "|", "./udpipe", "--tokenize", "--tag", "./path/to/my/model", ">>", "filename.txt"
proc = Popen(cmd, shell=True)
proc.wait()
```

Or you can apply higher level function [`subprocess.call()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.call):

```py
from subprocess import call

text = "the text I'm processing"
cmd = "echo", text, "|", "./udpipe", "--tokenize", "--tag", "./path/to/my/model", ">>", "filename.txt"
call(cmd, shell=True)
```

If you want to get process output in code, you can use another higher level function [`subprocess.check_output()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output):

```py
from subprocess import check_output

text = "the text I'm processing"
cmd = "echo", text, "|", "./udpipe", "--tokenize", "--tag", "./path/to/my/model"
output = check_output(cmd, text=True, shell=True)
print(output)
```

**BUT!** you can also use python functionality instead. For example, using `Popen()` you can pass input to process and *(if needed)* redirect it directly to file:

```py
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

text = "the text I'm processing"
cmd = "./udpipe", "--tokenize", "--tag", "./path/to/my/model"
proc = Popen(cmd, stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, text=True)
output, _ = proc.communicate(input=text)
print(output)
# OR write to file directly
with open("filename.txt", "a+") as out:
    proc = Popen(cmd, stdin=PIPE, stdout=out, stderr=out, text=True)
    proc.communicate(input=text)
```

Same with higher-level `check_output()`:

```py
from subprocess import check_output, STDOUT

text = "the text I'm processing"
cmd = "./udpipe", "--tokenize", "--tag", "./path/to/my/model"
output = check_output(cmd, input=text, stderr=STDOUT, text=True)
print(output)
```

Last option is what I'd use, but you can apply one you like most.